# Further information about last_query_cost in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, optimization, profiling

When doing query optimization, the `SHOW STATUS` query returns values that are easy to understand with some practice and explanation.

But `last_query_cost` is obscure and poorly documented.

The only thing explained is that it must be read as an anti-macho value: the smaller the better.

But do we have further information about this high-level value? What is its unit? How is it calculated (estimated)? etc. How can we use it for an advanced profiling?

Thanks for your precious help. :)

Comment: For the record: instead of using CLI command `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Last_query_cost';` you may obtain the same information by using plain SELECT query [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58582396/1174405). Works well if you execute queries not from CLI but by using client lib in your app and still  want to get `Last_query_cost`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with how the MySQL Query Optimizer works. When you enter and execute a query, MySQL will construct a query plan. This is done by evaluating how the query can be executed in several different ways, and assigning "costs" to the different possibilities. These costs are based mostly on internal statistics, and includes data such as the number of rows in the table, the cardinality of different indices and so forth. When this is done, MySQL choses the least expensive plan and executes the query. The last_query_cost value is this cost value.

As you've no doubt seen in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Last_query_cost):

> The total cost of the last compiled
>   query as computed by the query
>   optimizer. This is useful for
>   comparing the cost of different query
>   plans for the same query. The default
>   value of 0 means that no query has
>   been compiled yet. The default value
>   is 0. Last_query_cost has session
>   scope.

This is indeed true. The value is only useful as a quantitative measurement to compare different queries.

There's some interesting resources on the query optimizer available online, if you want to learn more. Unfortunately, I don't have any links for you readily available, but it shouldn't be too hard to find some resources through a simple search for "mysql query optimizer".

Comment: Exact! I found this link http://tinyurl.com/myw73d . Very informative! Now I really have to practice and understand how to interpret this value to make the right decision when optimizing. ;) Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: High Performance MySQL is an excellent book that I highly recommend.

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/10/15/a-case-study-in-profiling-queries-in-mysql/) makes it sound like it may simply be an estimation and therefore not something you should rely on for advanced profiling:

> One thing I didn't show you about
>   those two queries was the value of
>   Last_query_cost. That's because it
>   showed the slower, more data-intensive
>   query actually having a lower cost
>   than the faster one: Last Query Cost
>   in Table Redesign
>
> ```
> Variable_name    Design1       Design2
> Last_query_cost  20343.599000  71039.632551
> ```
>
> That's pretty bizarre, isn't it? I
>   don't know how the query cost is
>   calculated; I believe the optimizer
>   calculates it in advance of actually
>   executing the query. It definitely
>   doesn't match the actual cost of
>   executing these queries. It is usually
>   more in line with the true cost, but
>   not always. You should not rely on it
>   absolutely.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of cases I am trying to investigate/understand! :) last_query_cost seems more to be base on the query optimizer than on the execution. Or maybe not.

The fact that I cannot justify/predict this last_query_cost value (compared to all the other metrics) only tells me that I miss a piece. :)

Comment: It is odd how little information is out there describing this variable, especially considering that it came out with MySQL 5. Maybe nobody has found it to be accurate enough.